# How can i get a exact date using string without html5?

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is the string "2/29/16"
i want to use this to compute dates
can you suggest a way to use this string as a date?

Comment: Why are you talking about html5 ? which language do you use ?

Comment: Are you using PHP or?

Comment: @VincentDecaux I think he's asking about HTML5 because there's an `input type=date` there

Comment: i am using php and html. Im talking html5 because i saw html 5 support date function

Comment: HTML5 doesn't support date function, it supports `input type=date`...

Comment: thank you for the information.i appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '2/29/16';
$date = new DateTime($string);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

The output is

```
2016-02-29
```

On how to format a date object, [read in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

To format the today string:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Result:

```
2016-02-26
```

Comment: how can i compute with the date today using this? thank you

Comment: I updated my answer. The problem is you do not want to read the PHP manual. Meanwhile, it has all the answers you need.

Comment: Still I want to thank you for helping me. Next time ill read the manual :)